# How to make a pop up generated file download in Django 2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, download

I was working on a barcode image generate system and make pdf for printing.

Here is my **view.py**

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph

canvas.Canvas('assets/pdf_print/'+barCode+'.pdf')

c.drawImage('1.png',0.9*cm,0,3.5*cm,1.8*cm)
c.drawImage('1.png',4.8*cm,0,3.5*cm,1.8*cm)
c.drawImage('1.png',8.9*cm,0,3.5*cm,1.8*cm)
c.drawImage('1.png',12.7*cm,0,3.5*cm,1.8*cm)
c.drawImage('1.png',16.7*cm,0,3.5*cm,1.8*cm)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

I save that pdf file in this **path** successfully using report lab

> assets/pdf_print/

After saving that file in that path, I need to generate a popup download for this file.

How could I do that in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a href link the pop with link of view which returns PDF file as response

when the user clicks on that link the browser will prompt to save the file since it is a file response

```
from django.http import FileResponse, Http404

def pdf_view(request):
    try:
        return FileResponse(open('foobar.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise Http404()
```